# AWS Elastic beanstalk scale triggering

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I set the following parameters in my elastic beanstalk environment:

[image: settings]

1. Do you think this settings are reasonable?
2. I didn't understand the breach duration parameter. What does it means? is 5 minutes is reasonable?

Thanks

Comment: "Are these settings reasonable?" is a pretty broad question. Depends on your requirements, I'd say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This all depends. Different apps need to scale for different reasons. This is why Elastic Beanstalk lets you choose various ways to scale your application. Sure, this is reasonable. Does it work for your application? Not sure. Is your app CPU intensive or is it just serving static content? What is the number one factor to latency and 500's?
2. The breach duration parameter is the time frame of data to look at. For example, during the last 5 minutes, has the CPU been above 70%? Lower the number to be more "real time" and increase the number to be more "safe".

From [the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.as.html):

> For Measurement period, specify how frequently Amazon CloudWatch measures the metrics for your trigger. **Breach duration is the amount of time a metric can extend beyond its defined limit (as specified for Upper threshold and Lower threshold) before the trigger fires.**

Comment: I thought measurement period is the time frame of data to look at.  So what is the difference between breach duration and measurement period?

Comment: Measurement period is how OFTEN the measurements happen. So for example, if set to 7, the measurement happens every 7 minutes, checking the last 5 minutes of data. Edited answer.

Comment: Thanks, Very helpful! Regarding question 1, what will be the parameters to decide the value for each option?

Comment: @Shahar It really depends on your app. You need to do some load testing to see where your app starts to slow down. Is it iops latency? CPU load? Bandwidth? Threads?

Comment: I'll try that and post another thread. Thanks alot!